# How to listen user inputs on webview2 control in C# application?

Tags: c#, callback, webview2

I have a unique requirement where in my application I need to intercept user input on webview2 control and preprocess user input prior to posting.

I have started with a sample code from the following location :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms

I have tried following callbacks but none of them is called when the user enter any information on the input box or click the button

NavigationStarting
SourceChanged
ContentLoading
HistoryChanged
NavigationCompleted

Only time I get the handle is when it requires to reload.

Any thoughs ..

Comment: You must write some javascript (and inject it) to catch the events, then use the `window.chrome.webview.postMessage` method to post the value to your C# code. See https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms#step-8---communication-between-host-and-web-content

Comment: Thank you.  I have been to that page. Is there any example available for code injection.

Comment: You can use `CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(String)` method - check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addscripttoexecuteondocumentcreatedasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.774.44#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2_AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync_System_String_

Comment: You might be inspired by my answer here (it shows how to catch mouse clicks): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354344/how-detect-a-mouse-click-in-webview2-c-vb-net/65398068#65398068