# How to listen the mouse event of WebView2 in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, webview2

Is there any way to listen to the mouse move, hover, click events of WebView2?

I know it can be done through `js` and WebMessageReceived events.

[How detect a mouse click in webview2 (c#/vb.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354344/how-detect-a-mouse-click-in-webview2-c-vb-net)

But my production environment disables all scripts.

Is there any other way to achieve it?