# How to detect a mouse down using WebView2 in C# and then hiding the open MenuStrip?

Tags: c#, webview2, mousedown, menustrip

In a form I have a MenuStrip and a Webview2 component.
The MenuStrip does not close when you click on the Webview2 component.
I am unable to detect a mouse click using WebView2 in C# and so I cannot close the MenuStrip called   menuStrip1.
Can I just simple use the event webView21_MouseDown ?
I have tried all kinds of solutions found on the internet but I cannot get it to work.
What am I missing?

```
using System;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;  

namespace TestWebView2  
{  
    public partial class Form1 : Form  
    {  
        public Form1()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
            InitializeWebview2();  
        }  

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
        }  

        private async void InitializeWebview2()
        {
            await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        }

        private void webView21_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("it does not work");
        }

        private void webView21_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("it does not work");
        }
    }
}
```

The MenuStrip does not close when you click on the Webview2 component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How detect a mouse click in webview2 (c#/vb.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354344/how-detect-a-mouse-click-in-webview2-c-vb-net)

Comment: It looks like you need to use JavaScript in the WebView2 control to communicate with the application. An alternate approach would be to close the MenuStrip when it loses focus, using the OnLostFocus event of the MenuStrip.

Comment: I do not see an Event LostFocus or OnLostFocus when I select the webview in design mode.
I have tried this example, but it is VB.net and I could not get it to work with C#.

Comment: Thank squaabaam.
Finally got that C# example working.
Seems that javascript implementation only works if an HTML page is loaded first. With the click event in the javascript file it works to hide any open item in the menu.