# Closing dropdown menustrip in webview2

Tags: vb.net, webview2

I have in a desktop application a webpage with a menustrip. I use webview2 as webbrowser control. When i click on the menustrip the menu dropsdown. The problem is that the dropdown doesn’t hide when i click on the webpage. In the standard vb net webbrowser this is not happening.  So how can i hide the dropdown menu in webview2?

**Maybe the answer lies in VB net. I am looking for a method to close the dropdown of the menustrip of my form** i can call than this method from javascript on my webpage

Comment: Add this Javascript when the CoreWebView2 initialization completes: `document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) { window.chrome.webview.postMessage('MouseDown'); });`. Then `await [WebView2].CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync("[The Script String]")`. Add a handler to `WebMessageReceived`, where you check `if e.WebMessageAsJson.Contains("MouseDown")`, loop `[MenuStrip].Items.OfType(Of ToolStripMenuItem)()` and call `[item].HideDropDown()` on each. -- Note that this only works when a page is loaded, if the Control is blank, no event is raised.

Comment: This is still problem in the WinForms Control.. See also: [Webview2.Winforms.DOM](https://github.com/ukandrewc/Webview2.Winforms.DOM)

Comment: @jimi: Don't write such long comments that intent to to answer the question, write an answer!

Comment: @PoulBak It's not an answer, it's a *test this ugly thing, see whether it works for you*. I'm not sure it does (the WebView2 version is undefined, as it the UI Platform - yes, MenuStrip invokes WinForms). And, I don't really like it. If I can make it work with something like the CoreWebView2CompositionController or similar, I'll post it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you override the ContextMenu that appears when right clicking on WebView2 Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624373/how-do-you-override-the-contextmenu-that-appears-when-right-clicking-on-webview2)

Comment: @Poul Bak No it doesnt my answer.  I work with vb net 4.8 and json'object  doesnt work in 4.8 .

Comment: @user3025401: Yes, it does, just download the 'Newtonsoft' package: Select 'project', 'Nuget package' then download 'Newtonsoft' (that's what is used in that answer).

Comment: After installation, add `using Newtonsoft.Json;` to your class.

Comment: @Jimi That's a pity `WebView2` behaves like that, in addition I want to report more issues: the `MenuStrip` shortcuts/hotkeys will NOT work when the cursor is over the `WebView2` or it has been clicked, the `MenuStrip` doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Thanx Jimi and Poul i solved the issue.
It was quite simple thnx to you.
Solution:
1 my webpage is openlayers map  which has a eventlistner for click,

```
map.on('singleclick', function (event) {
    var lonLat = ol.proj.toLonLat(event.coordinate);
    var str = lonLat[0] + "," + lonLat[1];

(window.chrome.webview.hostObjects.sync.Bridge).Map_click(str);

});
```

Vb net
2.  i use a bridge between vb net and javascript
WebView21.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("Bridge", New Bridge()) to make a bridge between my vb net desktop application and the javascript on the Webppage.

3 I loop through the menu items and hide the dropdown of the menu item

```
Private Sub clearmenustrip() For Each mnuitem As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem In Fmenu.MenuStrip1.Items
        mnuitem.HideDropDown()
    Next
End Sub
```

MenuStrip1 is the menustrip in the Form

Comment: This solution does NOT solve the following: the `MenuStrip` shortcuts/hotkeys will NOT work when the cursor is over the `WebView2` or it has been clicked, the `MenuStrip` doesn't work as intended.