# Overriding Webview2 context menu along with default one

Tags: c#, webview2

Following the approach mentioned in the below link I was able to override default context menu.

[How do you override the ContextMenu that appears when right clicking on WebView2 Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624373/how-do-you-override-the-contextmenu-that-appears-when-right-clicking-on-webview2)

I have a question is there a way to show both based on some condition like

- Normal right-click - Custom Overridden context menu
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> press + right-click - default context menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually easy, when you have the code from that link.

The `contextmenu` event derives from `MouseEvent`, so it has information about the control keys being pressed.

Simply replace the javascript `contextmenu` handler to:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event)
{
    if (!event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey)
    {
        let jsonObject =
        {
            Key: 'contextmenu',
            Value:
            {
                X: event.screenX,
                Y: event.screenY
            }
        };
        window.chrome.webview.postMessage(jsonObject);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It works so that if a control key is pressed, it does absolutely nothing, which will show the default menu. If no keys are pressed, it sends the coordinates to C# and calls `event.preventDefault();`.

**Note**: In the code from that link, I call:

```
webView21.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
```

Here, you should NOT call that. Instead call `event.preventDefault();` in javascript.